Logisim latch oscillation issue
I would like to get familiar with latches, so I have build a circuit similar to an SR Latch. Logisim throws oscillation errors when I try to test it using different inputs. In my opinion the circuit should not be oscillating (maybe my understanding of oscillation is wrong).
The screenshot shows the circuit after I set the S (upper) pin to 0 from 1.
My question is, is the circuit fundamentally wrong, where is the logical error in the design?


Whether your design is fundamentally wrong, I cannot say. It depends on your requirements and/or design goals.
Logisim reports oscillation, if it cannot reach a stable state in the circuit after a number of simulation steps (default: 1000). This happens commonly with feedback loops. See chapter 8 in the online documentation for details.
Fortunately Logisim can help you to find the reason:

Open the menu "Simulate" and note the entries "Simulation Enabled" (Ctrl-E), "Reset Simulation" (Ctrl-R), and "Step Simulation" (Ctrl-I). Make sure the checkbox at "Simulation Enabled" is off.
Switch R from 0 to 1.
Now enable the simulation, and all error marker will go away. This is possible (probably accidentally) because of your current circuit.
Switch R back to 0.
Switch S from 0 to 1.
Now disable the simulation.
Switch S from 1 to 0.
Step the simulation, I'd recommend to use Ctrl-I for convenience.
Observe the changes via the wire colors and the pin markers (dark-blue circles).
Repeat the stepping.

Now you can see where the oscillation happens. Each gate has a delay of one step before it output its result. Apparently it is the feedback path through the topmost AND, which lets the circuit oscillate.
How to repair your circuit is your task. You will need to rethink your logic.

This answer will help me to further analyze the issue, many thanks.
